# C# image crop resize delete

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

When I try to delete image by using `System.IO.File.Delete(....)` then I get error exception.

`IOException was unhandled by user code`

The process cannot access the file 
'xxx\image\6132_15658422-b0a1-45a9-b0f9-7e9af783ad53_Temp.jpg' 
because 
it is being used by another process.

Could anyone please give me suggestion ?

---

---

My main function that crop, resize and delete image by c#.

```
    int X1 = 70, Y1 = 20, X2 = 201, Y2 = 236, w = 800, h = 600;
    string filelocation = "image/6132_15658422-b0a1-45a9-b0f9-7e9af783ad53_Temp.jpg";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image _Image = cropImage(
                                                ResizeImage(
                                                        System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( Server.MapPath("~") +"/"+  filelocation), w, h),
                                                        (new System.Drawing.Rectangle(X1, Y1, X2, Y2))))
            {
                _Image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/" + "image/output.jpg");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~") + "/" + filelocation);
        }
    }
```

For Crop Image Function,

```
    public System.Drawing.Image cropImage(System.Drawing.Image image, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(image);
            Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
            bmpImage.PixelFormat);
            return (System.Drawing.Image)(bmpCrop);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

For Resize Image Function,

```
    public System.Drawing.Image ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        try
        {
            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            return newImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

[Updated]

Finally I correct my problem as @landenedge suggested,

```
          using (var mainImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~") +"/"+  filelocation)){
                using (System.Drawing.Image _Image = cropImage(
                                                    ResizeImage(mainImage, w, h),
                                                            (new System.Drawing.Rectangle(X1, Y1, X2, Y2))))
                {
                    _Image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/" + "image/output.jpg");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Hint: "it is being used by another process" ....

Comment: yes, but I don't know which process is used already ...

Comment: Probably your own: Run ProcessMonitor ...It's free

Comment: You are creating new instances of `Bitmap`'s.. but not disposing of the ones you have open. You need to do that after you've created a new instance from an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose of the `Image` you create with `FromFile()`.  Try something like this:

```
using (var mainImage = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~") +"/"+  filelocation), w, h))
using (var _Image = cropImage(ResizeImage(mainImage, new Rectangle(X1, Y1, X2, Y2))))
{
    _Image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/" + "image/output.jpg");
}
```

Also, don't rethrow exceptions with `throw ex;` - doing so resets the stack trace and can drop valuable debugging information.  Instead, just use `throw;`.

Answer (score 2):

Even after you've matched up all your `Dispose()` statements you will find that you still have problems.  `Image.FromFile` is problematic in any high volume web site.  The solution is to use `Image.FromStream` instead.

```
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
     using (Image original = Image.FromStream(fs))
     {
      ...
```

Using an explicit `Dispose()`, a `using()` statement or setting the value to `null` **doesn't solve the issue** until a garbage collection happens. Forcing a garbage collection to happen is generally a bad idea.

Comment: notable suggestion about Image.FromFile vs Image.FromStream , Thank @Ian Mercer